# Is there a model of set theory in which $2^{2^{\omega_1}}$ is separable?

Tags: general-topology, descriptive-set-theory

We know that  $2^{\mathfrak c^+}$ ($\mathfrak c =2^\omega=|\mathcal P (\omega)|$) is not separable by the following argument:

Suppose $D$ is countable dense in $2^{\mathfrak c^+}$. For each $\alpha<\mathfrak c ^+$ we have  $D_\alpha=\pi_\alpha ^{-1} \{0\} \cap D\neq\varnothing $.  If $\alpha\neq\beta<\mathfrak c ^+$ then we have $D_\alpha \cap \pi_\beta ^{-1} \{1\} \neq\varnothing $ but $D_\beta \cap  \pi_\beta ^{-1} \{1\}=\varnothing $, whence $D_\alpha\neq D_\beta$.  So we have $\mathfrak c^+>\mathfrak c$ different subsets of our countable set $D$, which is a contradiction.

The same argument does not necessarily work for $2^{2^{\omega_1}}$: we would get $2^{\omega_1}$ many different subsets of a countable set, but this is not necessarily a contradiction(!)- there exist models of set theory (for instance any model in which Martin's Axiom holds), where you can have $2^\omega=2^{\omega_1}$. My question: In any of these models could we actually get $2^{2^{\omega_1}}$ separable?

Thank you!

Comment: Is the topology on $2^{\omega_1}$ discrete here?

Comment: @AsafKaragila $2^{\omega_1}$ is just the index for the product of copies of $2$. Maybe it should be written $2^{(2^{\omega_1})}$.  Both sets $2^{\mathfrak c ^+}$ and $2^{(2^{\omega_1})}$ have the product topology.

Comment: Wait a second... this is easy.  If $2^{\omega_1}=2^\omega$ then we have $2^{2^{\omega_1}}=2^{2^{\omega}}$, and we know a product of $2^\omega$ separable spaces is separable.  So in particular, MA implies $2^{2^{\omega_1}}$ is separable.

Comment: Well, $\mathsf{MA}+\neg\mathsf{CH}$ implies that $2^{(2^{\omega_1})}$ is separable. Might as well post your answery comment as an answer and accept it.